# Javascript fetch delete how to delete html

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Problem: I want to delete the HTML row when my Title 1 (or 2 or 3,...) gets deleted from the JSON on the server. Yet I'm only able to do this when I refresh.

I tried to add the AddCards method after every fetch call but then I would need to remove all tr elements but I tried that as well.

Here's a picture of the site.

[Picture of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yC0M.png)

This is the javascript code:

```
let form = document.getElementById('frm');
form.addEventListener('submit', PostBlog)
let alleposts = {};
let numOfPosts = 0;
getPosts();

function PostBlog(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let title = document.getElementById("txtTitle");
    let content = document.getElementById("txtContent");
    let data1 = {content: content.value,title:title.value};
    fetch("/posts",
    {
        method: 'POST',
        mode:'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data1),
    }
).then(receive).then(response => (response).text()).then(Succeed).catch(problem);
}
function receive(response) {
    if(!(response.ok)){
        throw new Error("Didn't Receive " + response.status);
    }
    return response;
}
function problem(error){
    alert("Not Found " + error);
}
function Succeed(data){
    alert("Found " + data);
    getPosts();
}

function getPosts(){
    fetch("/posts",{
        method:'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(receive).then(response => response.json()).then(Succeed2).catch(problem);
}

function Succeed2(data){
    alert("Found " + JSON.stringify(data));
    data.forEach((data) => alleposts[`${data.title}`] = data.uuid);
    AddCards();

}

function AddCards(){

    Object.keys(alleposts).forEach((sleutel)=>{VoegVorigePostToe(sleutel)});
}

function Succeed3(data){
    alert("Found " + data);
    numOfPosts--;
}

function DeletePost(event){
    let title = event.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    console.log(title);
    let key = alleposts[title];
    console.log("alle keys " + JSON.stringify(key));
    fetch(`/posts/${key}`,{
        method:'delete',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(receive).then(response => (response).text()).then(Succeed3).catch(problem);
}




function VoegVorigePostToe(title){
    //let title = document.getElementById("txtTitle");
    let thead = document.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];

    let th = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.setAttribute("id", "th_" + numOfPosts);
    td.innerText = title;
    let delete_button = document.createElement("td");
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Delete";
    button.addEventListener("click",DeletePost)



    delete_button.appendChild(button);
    th.appendChild(td);
    th.appendChild(delete_button);
    thead.appendChild(th);
    numOfPosts++;

}
```

The html id's like frm = form, txtTitle = title input box

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue as simple as you can? It sound like you have trouble syncing your data from your server to the client? In `DeletePost` you're *first* getting all the posts and *then* removing the post that you've clicked. Isn't it supposed to be the other way around?

Comment: I put in a title and some context, then I submit it so it gets added to the server json. If I wanna delete the post from the server I have to refresh before the fetch call finds it when I click the delete button. It's supposed to first get all posts then remove the one clicked so it's "up to date"

Comment: Ah I see. When you call the POST endpoint, does the server respond with an updated set of the JSON data? Same question goes for when using DELETE?

Comment: Yes that's the strange thing. It does update on the server itself but not on the page.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I was able to fix the problem with the fetch calls, yet I updated this post with the problem that remains. I've tried multiple ways to actually remove the html element tr when removed from the server. Yet that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it with:

```
function DeleteRow(event) {
    let btn = event.target;
    $(btn).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

Comment: Way to go! I see you've used jQuery to facilitate this, but nowadays you can do almost the same thing without jQuery: `btn.closest('tr').remove();` Both the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) methods are native to JS.